# Ionic add tap/click event dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a div that is added dynamically from a javascript framework. After this is done, I want to add an ionic click/tap handler to that specific div. How can I achieve this?

```
<ul ng-click=function(){}>
    <my_generated_div></my_generated_div>
</ul>
```

Comment: place that div inside a list and make it ng-click ="function()"

Comment: I updated the code, like that you mean?

Comment: `<ion-list> <ion-item ng-click = "you should write your function name not your function itself">  <my_generated_div></my_generated_div></ion-item><ion-list>`

Comment: I did a small test project, seems to be working. Thanks

Comment: No mention always welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener using its ID or class:

```
document.getElementById("yourDivID").addEventListener("click", function(){
   //YOUR CODE
});
```

or if you have a reference of the object:

```
yourObjectReference.addEventListener("click", function(){
   //YOUR CODE
});
```